# angular url with django url

Tags: django, angularjs, url-routing, angularjs-routing

I am making a Single Page Application using angularJS, django and django-rest-framework. All urls are specified in django and only those urls in which I want to load partials are specified in ng-routing.

Now in ng-view I can load partials for the urls specified in ng-routing.But lets say `/about` is not specified in angular but its there in django. When I do like this in ng-view:

`<a href="/about">about</a>`

then since this url is not in ng-routing required template is not rendered.

But this works-

`<a href="/about" target="_self">about</a>`

because on reloading the url is handled by django and it renders the template.

What is the DRY way of writing the django and angular urls so that I don't need to redundantly specify urls at two places i.e. django-urls and ng-routing, and angular can understand the django urls ?